# Regex for split c# string based on specific condition

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin.ios

I have this string

```
You have 6 uncategorized contacts from <an id='316268655'>SAP SE</an>
```

I want to collect 2 parts of string

- `you have 6 uncategorised contacts from`
- `<an >Sap SE </an>`

without id attribute below attempt was working

```
var parts = Regex.Split(value, @"(<an[\s\S]+?<\/an>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

But from the Time attribute Id is coming I am not able to parse it .

could anyone help me with syntax

Comment: Use `<an\b[^>]*>([^<]*)</an>`

Comment: It is not working for me :(

Comment: Breaking into 4 parts

Comment: <.*?>

above I tried and worked but again I can't get id out

Comment: See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3can%5cb%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e%28%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%29%3c%2fan%3e&i=You+have+6+uncategorized+contacts+from+%3can+id%3d%27316268655%27%3eSAP+SE%3c%2fan%3e) (see *Split List* tab).

Comment: sorry there was an error in requirement

Comment: Why not do that using an XML parser? Or `XElement`?

Comment: Its Xamarin we don't have that available

Comment: You are very close , just give me second string with tags attached this way I can know this string was inside tags

Comment: Anyway, my regex from the top comment gets you 2 expected values.

Comment: You are right I was wrong in my requirement , I need tags with that I can identify this part of string was inside tags so that I can apply my Ui design on it

Comment: D you mean you need the tags, too? Like [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3can%5cb%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%3c%2fan%3e%29&i=You+have+6+uncategorized+contacts+from+%3can+id%3d%27316268655%27%3eSAP+SE%3c%2fan%3e)?

Comment: Yes yes bro that correct I need em badly

Comment: See when I use above Regex I get 2 strings but second string is stripped of the tags I need the tags as well

Comment: [See this link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3can%5cb%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%3c%2fan%3e%29&i=You+have+6+uncategorized+contacts+from+%3can+id%3d%27316268655%27%3eSAP+SE%3c%2fan%3e). You need to put the `(` at the start and `)` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: my second last comment plz read ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get second part of your input, I have added code part after that -   here is complete code

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace PatternMatching
    {
        public class Program
        {
          public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "You have 6 uncategorized contacts from <an id='316268655'>SAP SE</an>";


       var parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(<an[\s\S]+?<\/an>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();   
              foreach(var a in parts)
              {
                   Console.WriteLine(a);
                   break;
              }
         string pattern = "<an.*?>(.*?)<\\/an>";      
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

       if (matches.Count > 0)
         foreach (Match m in matches)
               Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This program will give second output without tag, looks like you have edited the question and added tag also in second part output

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer because it will help you to find exact answer you want (tag in your second part)

```
public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
string input = "You have 6 uncategorized contacts from <an id='316268655'>SAP SE</an>";   

var parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(<an[\s\S]+?<\/an>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();  
string part="";
 foreach(var a in parts)
{
  part =a;
      if(a.Contains("<an")){
      part = Regex.Replace(a, @"(?i)<(an)(?:\s+(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^""'>])*)?>", "<$1>");

       }
        Console.WriteLine(part);
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```